# How to Save to a Custom Join Table Core Data (many-to-many) without unique predicate - ManagedObjectID (Swift)?

Tags: swift, core-data, many-to-many, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

I will be super thankful for any help. How can I save instances to a join table without a unique identifier as a predicate? Can I use the managed object id to check if the item exists already?

I'm building an app with different exercise plans. Each plan holds many exercise, and an exercise can belong to many plans. I have structured my data model to include a custom join table so that I can query the completion status of an exercise from within one plan.
[image]

I'm sourcing my data from a json file and would like to save it to core data. I'm able to correctly save my CoreExercise, and CorePlan tables, however am having difficulty understanding how to save the instance of the object in the intermediate join table, since I'm unsure of what predicate to use.
I've written a class function to check if the instance exists, and to save it if it doesn't.

```
class CoreExercisePlan: NSManagedObject {
  class func coreExercisesForExercisePlan(exerciseInfo: Exercise, planName: String, inManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> CoreExercisePlan? {

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "CoreExercisePlan")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate() // Search for ObjectID here? / How?

    if let exercisePlan = (try? context.executeFetchRequest(request))?.first as? CoreExercisePlan {
        print("we have this exercise plan already saved")
        return exercisePlan

    } else if let exercisePlan = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("CoreExercisePlan", inManagedObjectContext: context) as? CoreExercisePlan {
        exercisePlan.status = 0
        exercisePlan.progress = 0
        print("we are creating new object")
        return exercisePlan
    }
    return nil
}


private func updateDatabaseWithExercisePlans(){
    managedObjectContext?.performBlock {

        // Array of exercises for each plan:
        let coffeePlanExercises = self.coffeeExercises 
        let subwayPlanExercises = self.subwayExercises

        for exercise in coffeePlanExercises {
            _ = CoreExercisePlan.coreExercisesForExercisePlan(exercise, planName: "coffee", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
        }

        for exercise in subwayPlanExercises {
            _ = CoreExercisePlan.coreExercisesForExercisePlan(exercise, planName: "subway", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
        }

        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext?.save()
        } catch let error {
            print("printing error here: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the objectID of the instance in the join table, and use that as a predicate? Thanks!

Comment: When you load CoreExercises and CorePlans, how do you uniquely identify them?  You could use the same criteria to uniquely identify the CoreExercisePlans (i.e. you fetch  the CoreExercisePlan for a particular CoreExercise in a particular CorePlan).

Comment: @pbasdf thanks for your comment. I identify them through a predicate on their name: request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", exercise.name). Can I search for this same exercise name in the predicate for ExercisePlan?

Comment: Something like this: NSPredicate(format: "exercise.name = %@ AND plan.name == %@", exercise.name, planName)

Comment: Thanks @pbasdf. I'm getting a: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "exercise.name = %@ AND plan.name. I take it the first part of the predicate can refer to the attribute names of related objects? fyi I'm receiving both exercise name and plan name as strings.

Comment: My bad, I had a typo. Now have a: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'. I'll research this more on SO. Thanks so much already @pbasdf

Comment: Ah yes - your relationship from CoreExercisePlan to CoreExercise is to-many.  Do you need that?  I was expecting it was to-one.

Comment: (As a newbie) I thought so. Since one exercise can be in several different exercise plans. And one exercise plan has many different exercises. @pbasdf

Comment: @pbasdf , I got it with format: "exercise.name CONTAINS[cd] %@ && plan.name = %@"...thanks to you and your feedback!